# Run time error while trying to insert data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I'm traying to insert data into my microsoft database but this run time error is thrown

> "Incorrect syntax near 'date'.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@\"."

in this line `Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

here is my code

```
        public void InsertInventory(DateTime _date, int _customer_Id,
                            int _employee_Id, List<int> _product_Id,
                            List<int> _amountSold,
                            List<int> _unitPrice, List<int> _totalPrice)
    {
        Connection_String = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog="
                           + "Sales and Inventory System"
                           + ";Integrated Security=TrueData Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog="
                           + "Sales and Inventory System"
                           + ";Integrated Security=True;";

        Query = "insert into Inventory" +
                  "(Customer_Id,Employee_Id,Product_Id,[Date],[Amount Sold],[Unit Price],[Total Price])" +
                    "values (@customer_id,@Employee_id,@Product_id,@[Date],@[Amount_Sold],@[Unit_Price],@[Total_Price])";

        using (Con = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
        using (Cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Con))
        {
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Employee_id", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Product_id", SqlDbType.Int);
           //Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Date]", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Date]", SqlDbType.Date);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Amount_sold]", SqlDbType.Int);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@[Unit_Price]", SqlDbType.Decimal);
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total_Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);

            Cmd.Connection = Con;
            Con.Open();

            int RecordToAdd = _product_Id.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < RecordToAdd; i++)
            {
                Cmd.Parameters["@customer_id"].Value = _customer_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Employee_id"].Value = _employee_Id;
                Cmd.Parameters["@[Date]"].Value = _date;
                Cmd.Parameters["@Product_id"].Value = _product_Id[i];  
                Cmd.Parameters["@[Amount_sold]"].Value = _amountSold[i];
                Cmd.Parameters["@[Unit_Price]"].Value = _unitPrice[i];
                Cmd.Parameters["@Total_Price"].Value = _totalPrice[i];
                Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the parameter names, you don't need to wrap with [] you can just use @Date, @AmountSold, @UnitPrice, @TotalPrice. Just make sure you fix them in both the statement and the parameter lists